# Qlikview - Count with Conditional Expression

Tags: count, conditional-statements, expression, qlikview

I have a pivot table visual, with 4 dimensions and 3 measures - please refer to the attached image.
I want to filter out records with Total Volume less than 20. Can I get some recommendation on how I can acheive that. Of the 4 dimensions, Origin City and Mode are calculated dimensions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something quick and dirty that will do the trick :

```
Sum(if(TotalVolume >= 20, TotalVolume))
```

It's valid for other measures, so you could also do :

```
Avg(if(TotalVolume >= 20, DaysToLoad)
```

The most efficient way would be to use a set analysis, something like :

```
Sum( {<TotalVolume = {">=20"}>} TotalVolume)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Could you mark my answer as the correct one? As the owner of the question you are the only one who can do it, that will help others to focus on this response. The answer should have a green check mark on the size when it's done. Thanks!